# Passing id parameter from Laravel Collection to Vue Component

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

In my blade.php file I currently have a variable `$item` when dumped equates to:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2313 ▼
  #items: array:48 [▶]
}
```

Then in my blade.php file I am calling a Vue component and am attempting to bind and pass a route (route should dynamically render an item by its id in Vue) and it looks like:

```
 <my-items
   :route="{{ json_encode(route('items.show', ['id' => $item->id])) }}"
  ></my-items>
```

But when I reload my page I get this error:

```
Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.
```

Dump of $items

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2371 ▼
#items: array:48 [▼
0 => App\Items {#2351 ▶}
1 => App\Items {#2350 ▶}
2 => App\Items {#2349 ▶}
3 => App\Items {#2348 ▶}
4 => App\Items {#2347 ▶}
5 => App\Items {#2346 ▶}
6 => App\Items {#2345 ▶}
7 => App\Items {#2344 ▶}
8 => App\Items {#2343 ▶}
9 => App\Items {#2342 ▶}
10 => App\Items {#2341 ▶}
11 => App\Items {#2340 ▶}
12 => App\Items {#2339 ▶}
13 => App\Items {#2338 ▶}
14 => App\Items {#2337 ▶}
15 => App\Items {#2336 ▶}
16 => App\Items {#2335 ▶}
17 => App\Items {#2334 ▶}
18 => App\Items {#2333 ▶}
19 => App\Items {#2332 ▶}
20 => App\Items {#2331 ▶}
21 => App\Items {#2330 ▶}
22 => App\Items {#2329 ▶}
23 => App\Items {#2328 ▶}
24 => App\Items {#2327 ▶}
25 => App\Items {#2326 ▶}
26 => App\Items {#2325 ▶}
27 => App\Items {#2324 ▶}
28 => App\Items {#2323 ▶}
29 => App\Items {#2322 ▶}
30 => App\Items {#2321 ▶}
31 => App\Items {#2320 ▶}
32 => App\Items {#2319 ▶}
33 => App\Items {#2318 ▶}
34 => App\Items {#2317 ▶}
35 => App\Items {#2316 ▶}
36 => App\Items {#2315 ▶}
37 => App\Items {#2314 ▶}
38 => App\Items {#2313 ▶}
39 => App\Items {#2312 ▶}
40 => App\Items {#2311 ▶}
41 => App\Items {#2310 ▶}
42 => App\Items {#2309 ▶}
43 => App\Items {#2308 ▶}
44 => App\Items {#2307 ▶}
45 => App\Items {#2306 ▶}
46 => App\Items {#2305 ▶}
47 => App\Items {#2304 ▶}
]
}
```

How do I pass the id's of all the items to my vue component so that they may be dynamically rendered using vue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your blade file:

```
@foreach ($item as $items)
    <ItemComponent
        v-bind:item="{{ json_encode($item) }}"
    />
@endforeach
```

This will pass the full item object to each ItemComponent, if you only want to pass the id then you can use `:itemId="{{ json_encode($item->id) }}"` instead.

If you want to keep the looping logic in Vue, then refer to my previous answer with http requests instead of inline templating:

Instead your laravel back-end endpoint should respond after being called from your Vue wrapper component with the array of IDs in the response body. Then you can iterate over each ID in the array in Vue with the v-for directive.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="item" v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
            <ItemComponent :item="item"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            items: []
        }
    },
    created: function() {
        // When component instance has loaded (page load)
        // Call your laravel endpoint
        this.$http.get("/laravel/endpoint").then((res) => {
            this.items = res.body.items
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

Now, if you want to pass **one** ID as a route parameter, then you can access them with `$route.params.id` in your component, where 'id' is the name of the parameter which you setup in your vue router with

```
{
    path: '/path/to/view/:id'
    ...
}
```

Comment: I actually want to pass the items in and have them be accessible by their id but I want each item to be an object since I need to access the object properties using object notation.

Comment: @PA-GW The items array can be an array of objects. I edited my response to pass each item object to an item component where the items properties can be accessed using object notation.

Comment: so am I not longer passing my items to vue using the ```:route``` prop? Now I am retrieving the items with the ```this.$http.get()``` ?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an array. So you have to use `foreach` or `$item[index]->id`

Comment: I need to loop through them in my blade file then pass it to my vue components ```:route``` ?

Comment: Can you share a full dump image? It will help to give the solution. And I think yes you need to use loop.

Comment: do you use loop? try @foreach($item as $singleItem) then in this loop use $singleItem->id

Comment: I wanted to keep all of the looping logic in Vue not so much in blade.

Comment: then you have to get these data in the component file by vue resource or you can use axios.